# How to identify a transaction in Bitcoin

Tags: payment, payment-processors

I have a webshop, and I would accept Bitcoin payment. I have a Bitcoin address where I accept payment.

Is it a procedure to pass an id or ask an id to / from the transaction? When I query the received transactions I nee to know to which program it was bought. Who is the user, what is its email.

At other payment providers that create a `paymentId` and return it to the shop, and that `paymentId` will be also in the payment I can fetch later. How could it work with Bitcoin?

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/42763/5406 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to give every single transaction its own, unique Bitcoin address to receive the payment at (you should not reuse them). Then, you know any payment made to that particular address should be credited to the invoice that that address was issued for.

Most places don't ask for a transaction ID. They simply automatically check all of the addresses they've given out, then credit the payment according to which address the payment was sent to.