# Why can't bitcoin be stolen in the following manner?

Tags: private-key, public-key, utxo-set

Assume I'm a miner. I would have the complete UTXO set with me. Let us say I try generating random keys and hash the public keys generated and compare it with the utxo set until I find a match.
When I find a match, I can transfer the money of that address to my own account since I would have the private key as I myself generated the key.
Why would this not work?
(I'm pretty new to bitcoin, so apologies if this is a stupid question)

Comment: What is your estimate of the expected time until the first success?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105180/13866