# What is the probability of accidentally getting a seed phrase that is associated with a real address with a balance in the bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: public-key, seed, key-collision

Good afternoon! Such a question is interesting, and with what probability can you accidentally get a seed phrase that is associated with a real address with a balance in the bitcoin blockchain?

Comment: The probability asked will I believe depend on the input entropy in the seed phrase for the key derivation function; on how many "real address with a balance in the bitcoin blockchain" have been generated with it (it's improbable to find others); and on how many attempts are made. All this is so bitcoin-specific that there was no choice beside migration from Crypto-SE, where the question and a [first answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/120644/30768) originated.

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/8804/5406 answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Seeds are usually on the order of 128 bits of entropy.

2^128 = 3.4028237e+38

That's 38 zeroes.

Furthermore, each attempt is somewhat costly because it uses a good derivation function. So you can't even try very many.

This is for entire wallet collisions. For addresses, Bitcoin uses a 160 bit hash which is an even harder ordeal.